# Can't capture values return from Navigator.of(context).pop("value")

Tags: flutter, navigation, return

I navigate to a new screen with following manner

```
final result = await Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => PreLog(             
        ),
      ),
    );

    if (result != null) {
      print("Back");
    }
```

Inside PreLog got to several other screens following manner;

```
 Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => MyMap(
          ),
        ),
      );
```

In the final screen I come back following manner;

```
Navigator.of(context).pop("value");
```

I expected the value to be returned to the first screen. But it didn't.
How do I get values from the last screen back?

---

I have modified my question based on responses below.

In the main screen I am pushing PopTest widget

```
final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => PopTest(),
      ),
    );

    print(result);
```

From PopTest I am loading another replacement widget "PopTest2"

```
class PopTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PopTestState createState() => _PopTestState();
}

class _PopTestState extends State<PopTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Exit"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop("value from 1");
          },
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Load Next"),
          onPressed: () async {
            final result2 = await Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => PopTest2(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class PopTest2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PopTestState2 createState() => _PopTestState2();
}

class _PopTestState2 extends State<PopTest2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Exit"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop("value from 2");
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

If I exit from PopTest I do get a return value.

But if I exit from PopTest2 I DON'T get a return value.

Can anyone provide some help on this?

Comment: I think the issue maybe I push replacements to the pushed widget. But I don't understand why I can't return value though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting rootNavigator to true which places your pushed widget/screen to root of your app which has no widgets/screens behind it.

Omit rootNavigator:true in your code (it is false by default)

```
final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => PreLog(             
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Prelog Page(below)

```
// result2 is a variable with scope accessible to Navigator.pop()

result2 = await Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => MyMap(
          ),
        ),
      );

//when you are returning back 
Navigator.of(context).pop(result2);
```

---

EDITED ANSWER:: (after edited question)

Previously, I missed that you were pushing a page replacement.

See these Images for better understanding:: [Main Screen of App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg2YG.jpg),[Screen One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5iMQ.jpg),[Screen Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVzyP.jpg)

In the navigation stack, we have Main Screen(which awaits a result from PopTest1 Screen) and PopTest1 Screen.

When you push PopTest2 Widget as a replacement screen, your navigation stack now has Main Screen(**which gets a result from PopTest1 Screen**) and PopTest2 Screen. Read [pushRelpacement api docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushReplacement.html).

PopTest1 is now replaced by PopTest2 from the stack. Also, PopTest1's "OnPressed Function" is awaiting result.

That is why you are not able to get value to your Main Screen.

You can solve this by

1. passing **value** optional parameter in the pushReplacement call of PopTest1 Widget. Check out [flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushReplacement.html).
2. Using Named routing. Check out [Reso Coder's blog](https://resocoder.com/2019/04/27/flutter-routes-navigation-parameters-named-routes-ongenerateroute/) .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need to display pushed widget in full screen. How do I do that?

Comment: To display the pushed widget in full screen, you need to either, add some logic to your, say, bottom bar code such that it renders with zero height(or does not renders at all) , or use any state management solution ( refer https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt ). I have once used bloc library ( https://bloclibrary.dev/#/ ) to do the same, though any of the state management options will do what you want.